# Android emulator has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Emulators were working very well on my computer. I deleted the Android Studio and re-install it again in my D partition. Because my storage capacity is limited.

But now when I try to create a virtual device, it's not working. It says :

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04
Solution

1. I created **enough space on my disk drive**, at least 20 - 30GB free space. (30 GB is safer)

**Also Note:**

a). Make sure you installed emulator using image that is recommended by google, avoid x86 and or other images.

[image]

b). From Android studio menu, go to: Tools-> SDK Manager->SDK Tools-> (Update Android Emulator, Android Sdk Tools, Android Sdk platform Tools and Android Sdk build tool)

That is what worked for me. Hope it does the magic.